# Ext4 suitable Partition backup tool?

Tags: backup, clone

I just tried `partimage` , it doesn't have a EXT4 support officially , all my partition was displayed as ext3fs , and my LVM volume are named as dm-X.

So i'm wondering if there's another workable `graphical` or `semi-graphical` tool for backing up a partition ?

Thanks !

Comment: `partimage` works on ext2, ext3, and ext4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the Clonezilla Live CD/DVD/USB: http://clonezilla.org/

Personally, I use [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page), but that's command-line only.

Answer (score 0):

unmount the particular partition & then use fsarchiver to backup. if you want to backup root partition, then you may need to use system-rescue CD or linux distro installed on another partition.

after restoring root partition you may have to restore grub also.